# select substring between two matching strings

Tags: r, string, perl

I have three files: *File 1* contains a number of stings like below:

```
AGGUGCAGAGCUUAGCUGAUUGGUGAACAGUGAUUGGUUUCCGCUUUGUUCACAGUGGCUAAGUUCUGCACCU
```

*File 2* contains a substring of the string in file 1 matching the **left** side:

```
AGGUGCAGAGCUUAGCUGAUUGGUGAACAGUGAUUGGUUUCCGCUUUGUUCACAGUGGCUAAGUUCUGCACCU
      AGAGCUUAGCUGAUUGGUGAAC
```

*File 3* contains a substring of the string in file 1 matching the **right** side:

```
AGGUGCAGAGCUUAGCUGAUUGGUGAACAGUGAUUGGUUUCCGCUUUGUUCACAGUGGCUAAGUUCUGCACCU
                                                UUCACAGUGGCUAAGUUCUGC
```

I want to extract the string that lies between the two strings that match

```
AGGUGCAGAGCUUAGCUGAUUGGUGAACAGUGAUUGGUUUCCGCUUUGUUCACAGUGGCUAAGUUCUGCACCU
      AGAGCUUAGCUGAUUGGUGAAC                    UUCACAGUGGCUAAGUUCUGC
```

Output:

```
                            AGUGAUUGGUUUCCGCUUUG
```

I would like to do this for all my strings in *file 1* (approx 200 strings)

example *file 1*:

```
>mmu-let-7g
CCAGGCTGAGGTAGTAGTTTGTACAGTTTGAGGGTCTATGATACCACCCGGTACAGGAGATAACTGTACAGGCCACTGCCTTGCCAGG
>mmu-let-7i
CTGGCTGAGGTAGTAGTTTGTGCTGTTGGTCGGGTTGTGACATTGCCCGCTGTGGAGATAACTGCGCAAGCTACTGCCTTGCTAG
>mmu-miR-1a-1
GCTTGGGACACATACTTCTTTATATGCCCATATGAACCTGCTAAGCTATGGAATGTAAAGAAGTATGTATTTCAGGC
```

Example *file 2* and *file 3*:

```
>mmu-let-7g-5p MIMAT0000121 Mus musculus let-7g-5p
UGAGGUAGUAGUUUGUACAGUU
>mmu-let-7g-3p MIMAT0004519 Mus musculus let-7g-3p
ACUGUACAGGCCACUGCCUUGC
>mmu-let-7i-5p MIMAT0000122 Mus musculus let-7i-5p
UGAGGUAGUAGUUUGUGCUGUU
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try:

```
str1 <- "AGGUGCAGAGCUUAGCUGAUUGGUGAACAGUGAUUGGUUUCCGCUUUGUUCACAGUGGCUAAGUUCUGCACCU"
leftstr <- "AGAGCUUAGCUGAUUGGUGAAC"
rightstr <- "UUCACAGUGGCUAAGUUCUGC"

library(qdap)
 unname(genXtract(str1,leftstr, rightstr))
#[1] "AGUGAUUGGUUUCCGCUUUG"
```

#### Update

If you have multiple strings

```
 str2 <- c(str1, "AGGUGUCCCCCCUUUUUGGAGUGGCCGCUUUUGCGGGGUAAUUG")
 leftstr1 <- c(leftstr, "CCCCCUUUU")
 rightstr1 <- c(rightstr, "UUUUGCGG")
 unlist(genXtract(str2, leftstr1, rightstr1))
 #[1] "AGUGAUUGGUUUCCGCUUUG" "UGGAGUGGCCGC"
```

Comparing the results with @Venkataramanan's post

```
 temp1 <- mapply(gsub, leftstr1, "|", str2)
 temp2 <- mapply(gsub, rightstr1, "|", temp1)
  unlist(strsplit(temp2, "|", fixed=T),use.names=F)[c(F,T,F)]
 #[1] "AGUGAUUGGUUUCCGCUUUG" "UGGAGUGGCCGC"
```

or

```
   scan(text=gsub(paste(rightstr1, collapse="|"),
  " ",gsub(paste(leftstr1,collapse="|")," ",str2)),
  what="character")[c(F,T,F)]
#Read 6 items
# [1] "AGUGAUUGGUUUCCGCUUUG" "UGGAGUGGCCGC"
```

or

```
 library(stringr)
  str_extract_all(str1, perl(paste0("(?<=",leftstr,")",".*(?=", rightstr,")")))[[1]]
 #[1] "AGUGAUUGGUUUCCGCUUUG"
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are working with something like this:

```
file1 <- "AGGUGCAGAGCUUAGCUGAUUGGUGAACAGUGAUUGGUUUCCGCUUUGUUCACAGUGGCUAAGUUCUGCACCU"
file2 <- "AGAGCUUAGCUGAUUGGUGAAC"
file3 <- "UUCACAGUGGCUAAGUUCUGC"
```

You can try constructing your search pattern with "file2" and "file3" and using `gsub`.

Example:

```
gsub(paste0("(^.*", file2, ")(.*)(", file3, ".*)$"), "\\2", file1)
# [1] "AGUGAUUGGUUUCCGCUUUG"
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code does the job:

```
temp1<- gsub("AGAGCUUAGCUGAUUGGUGAAC", "|", "AGGUGCAGAGCUUAGCUGAUUGGUGAACAGUGAUUGGUUUCCGCUUUGUUCACAGUGGCUAAGUUCUGCACCU")
temp1
temp2<- gsub("UUCACAGUGGCUAAGUUCUGC","|", temp1)
temp2
unlist(strsplit(temp2, "|", fixed=T))[2]
```

Comment: Warning message:
In gsub(fivep, "|", hairpin) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: how does it work when I have the stings stored in files?

Comment: `user3741035`.  If you have multiple strings:  temp1 <- mapply(`gsub`,fivep,"|", hairpin); temp2 <- mapply(`gsub`, tailp, "|", temp1); unlist(strsplit(temp2,"|", fixed=T))[c(F,T,F)]