# Select substring bracketed by two whitespaces

Tags: regex, r, string, whitespace

I am using regular expressions in R.

My question is somewhat similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24779588/select-substring-between-two-matching-strings), but I need a more specific solution. I have a character vector. Each string is formatted like this:

```
"text    text1     text2  text3"
```

with lots of whitespace between the text chunks. I want to extract text1 from every string. Text1 always has at least two whitespaces on either side, but so does every other text chunk. Text1 will be a name like "Monty Python": may contain a space, but never two spaces.

I'm using `stringr`, and the `str_extract` function extracts only a pattern's first occurrence. But I am not sure how to specify my pattern. I tried `str_extract(z, "\\s{2,}[a-z]*\\s{2,}")`, indicating that I wanted at least one letter between the whitespaces. That resulted in NAs. Is there a way to isolate text1?

Comment: Your example string has 1 space on each side of "text1".  The pattern `"\\s{2,}[a-z]*\\s{2,}"` says to look for at least 2 white-space characters followed by zero or more lower case letters (a - z), then two or more white-space characters.  With your example string, there will be no matches for that pattern, as none of the words has 2 spaces on each side, and only one of the words (i.e. `text`) has only lowercase letters.

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't clear--"text1" does have multiple spaces on either side as I typed it, but the question only displays single spaces. Thanks for the headsup about lowercase letters though. Would `"\\s{2,}[A-Z]*.*[A-Z].*[a-z]*\\s{2,}"` work for what I'm attempting?

Comment: Can you provide some example strings?  Why not just search for "text1" or whatever your target string is?  Why do you need regular expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to acknowledge the letter case since your substring could have lower/upper case letters and include an optional group construct to match the second word instance of the substring.

Character vector (based off your description of input):

```
x <- c('foo    Monty Python      baz        quz',
       'foo    Monty        baz         quz')
```

Using the **stringr** package:

```
str_trim(str_extract(x, "\\s{2,}[a-zA-Z]+( [a-zA-Z]+)?\\s{2,}"))
# [1] "Monty Python" "Monty"
```

Using the regular expression in base R:

```
trimws(regmatches(x, gregexpr('\\s{2,}[a-zA-Z]+( [a-zA-Z]+)?\\s{2,}', x)))
# [1] "Monty Python" "Monty"
```

Although, I would simply just utilize **strsplit** here:

```
sapply(strsplit(x, '\\s{2,}'), '[', 2)
# [1] "Monty Python" "Monty"
```